# How to bind the text property of textblock with a file name

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I have a textblock in cell template and when the dialog box opened up and file selected i would like to change my text property of textblock from upload to the file name

XAML:

```
<Button Name="UploadButton" Click="UploadButton_Click" BorderBrush="Transparent"  Width="250" Height="50" Command="{Binding  Data.UploadFileCommand, Source={StaticResource proxy}}" Background="Transparent">
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
       <fa:ImageAwesome Icon="Upload" Foreground="Gray" Height="20" Width="20"/>
       <TextBlock x:Name="Attach"  Text="{Binding Path=Attachment,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
    </StackPanel>
</Button>
```

CODE:

```
OpenFileDialog fileDialog = new OpenFileDialog();
fileDialog.Multiselect = false;
fileDialog.Filter = "AutoCad Files(*.bmp;*.dxf)|*.bmp;*.dxf|Pdf files(*.pdf)|*.pdf|Image Files(*.img)|*.img";
Nullable<bool> result = fileDialog.ShowDialog();
string filepath = fileDialog.FileName;
string filename = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(filepath);
if (result == true)
{
    TextBlock text = new TextBlock();

    var yourType = ((FrameworkElement)sender).DataContext as TextBlock;
    yourType.Inlines.Add(filename);

}
```

Comment: You already binding `Text="{Binding Attachment, ... }"`, simply set that property to file name. Or what is exactly the problem?

Comment: Note also that setting `UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged` on the Text Binding is pointless. It has no effect.